# Dynamic Dates in Google Data Studio + Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, looker-studio

There is the solution how to make dynamic dates in Custom Queries `(Data Studio + BigQuery)` with reserved parameters @DS_START_DATE and @DS_END_DATE:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gdpt.png

But how can I do the same in the case of `Data Studio + Posgresql`?
Especially add into query `@DS_START_DATE and @DS_END_DATE parameters`??

Will highly appreciate your help!

Comment: Please do not link to off-site resource. Your question should be self-contained by providing all necessary information as part of the question. Please **[edit]** it it (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 4):

As of Nov 2019, custom parameters are not supported directly for the native Postgres connector in Data Studio.

However, you can achieve the same effect by creating a wrapper custom connector in Apps Script that fetches data from your Postgres database. Info on [Community Connectors](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/) and [Overridable parameters](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/data-source-parameters).

Comment: Can I get more information/document to write wrapper custom connector for postgres? I tried to find it but I couldn't.

Comment: Build a [Community Connector](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/) using [Apps Script JDBC Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc).

Comment: Hi Minhaz, do you have any link about "As of Nov 2019, custom parameters are not supported directly for the native Postgres connector in Data Studio." i couldn't find any info about it in the official documentation

Comment: [Parameters Help Center Doc](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9002005?hl=en) explicitly states that parameters can be passed back only to BigQuery connector and community connectors.

Comment: @MinhazKazi I've faced the same issue as the author of this question. Does Google Data Studio still missed this functionality for PostgreSQL connector? As for me there is a double work to create Community connector which will replicate the whole PostgreSQL logic only to get the "Parameters" feature..